# Python classes: having instance method in one class point to instance method in another class

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, docstring

I have a class (I will call it "master class") that uses instance methods from multiple other classes.  The other classes are imported on `__init__` and are stored as private instance attributes.

I would like to use the other class's instance methods, with the following properties:

- Not rewrite docstrings or signature in the master class
- Have `autodoc` parse the docstrings from the other classes as if they were docstrings for the master class

Currently, the way I have it set up:

```
class OtherClass:
    """Some other class that I import."""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def print_num(self, num: float = 15) -> None:
        """Print a num.

        Args:
            num: Number to print

        """
        print(num)
```

```
from .other import OtherClass


class MasterClass:

    def __init__(self, other_class: OtherClass):
        """Create master class with a bunch of other classes.

        For simplicity, I only included one class here as an arg.

        Args:
            other_class: Houses some methods

        """
        self._other_class = other_class

    def print_num(self, num: float = 15):
        """Print a num.

        Args:
            num: Number to print

        """
        self._other_class.print_num(num)
```

To pull in `OtherClass.print_num`, I had to:

1. Manually copy the signature
2. Manually copy the docstring (because I want my Sphinx documentation to be accurate)
3. Call `OtherClass`'s method within `MasterClass`'s method, passing in all the args and kwargs manually

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`wraps` from the module functools](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is what you need:

```
from functools import wraps

class OtherClass:
    def print_num(self, num: float=15) -> None:
        """Print a num.

        Args:
            num: Number to print

        """
        print(num)

class MasterClass:
    def __init__(self, other_class: OtherClass):
        self._other_class = other_class

    @wraps(OtherClass.print_num)
    def print_num(self, num=15):
        self._other_class.print_num(num)

print(MasterClass.print_num.__doc__)
print(MasterClass.print_num.__annotations__)
```

Output:

```
Print a num.

        Args:
            num: Number to print


{'num': <class 'float'>, 'return': None}
```

You still have to make the explicit call.

Note: your design is a special case of the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: thank you so much for an informational answer, I was not previously aware of the facade pattern!